# How to check duplicatechecks in csvbulkloader (silverstripe) by checking 2 colomn values in csv

Tags: php, silverstripe

```
public $columnMap = array(

    'Date'      => 'Date',
    'FirstName' => 'FirstName',
    'amount'      =>  'Amount',


);
public $duplicateChecks = array(
    'FirstName' => 'FirstName',
);
```

In `$duplicateChecks` I need to check FirstName and amount. How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you specify more on what you need to check against what?

Comment: I want to upload this 3 colomn csv to my db. But i want to check duplicates in db by concatinating firstname and amount

Comment: You mean if FirstName = Dan and Amount = 1, then this is only a duplicate with other rows that are FirstName = Dan and Amount = 1; but not duplicates of FirstName = Dan and Amount = 2 or FirstName = Nad and Amount = 1?

Comment: Duplicates for FirstName = Dan and Amount = 1

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/2542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have a composite check of two columns to identify a duplicate.

In this case you will need to provide your own bulk loader / import class and overload the `findExistingObject` method.

You could do something like:

```
class MyCsvBulkLoader extends CsvBulkLoader
{
    ...

    public function findExistingObject($record, $columnMap = [])
    {
        return DataObject::get($this->objectClass)
            ->filter(array(
                'FirstName' => $record['FirstName'],
                'amount' => $record['amount'],
            ))->first();
    }

    ...
}
```